# How can I compare the speed of the various caching frameworks?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching

I wish to compare the Read, Write and Read/Write speed for a burst of data on the following caching platforms:

1. EhCache
2. Redis
3. MemCached
4. GemFire
5. JCS (Java Caching System)

How can I do so? How can I make use of platforms like Spring and/or Hibernate in doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Just implement an example application and compare the speeds.

Long answer: The products you mention are very different. You can use them in different usage scenarios. E.g. I would roughly categorize it as follows:

- Inside Java heap: JCS, EhCache
- Off Java heap: MemCached
- Distributed: Redis
- Persistent: Redis

I left out GemFire, since I don't know anything about it.

Also you cannot do a direct comparison since the APIs are very different. For redis and memcache you use a rest interface. Theoretically it should be possible to implement for every product a JSR107 like API, so you can run a single test on the products. But again, that is senseless, since the products serve different purposes. For a real solution, it might be better to combine redis and EhCache. One solution for scaling and persistence, one solution for handling the caching part for Java objects within the Java heap.

I have done some benchmarking of Java caches. However it just covers the inside heap part, and runs only single threaded, so there is need for extension. For an entry look on the [cache2k benchmarks](http://cache2k.org/benchmarks.html) page. The benchmark code is on github and runs OOTB. If you want to contribute to it, you're very welcome!

Comment: Strict heap only: Guava etc ... for small projects (desktop for "normal user") may be important config-free etc. so no path to filesystem, connections etc. many small cache project are very fast, but non scalable to cluster etc. Chache2k if I remember was very fast

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use JMeter, where you can create some jobs to test the functionality of you application and create some Benchmarks.
http://jmeter.apache.org/